# SPDT switch mechanical drawing confusion from China vendor

Tags: toggle-switch

I'm looking into this simple slider switch schema (MSK12C02), but I'm confused with the mechanical drawing here

[image]

Assuming legs labeled `1,2,3` from bottom-right diagram, is the *common end* on

- `2`
- or both `1 & 2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Common is pin 2, the center pin. "A" shows you which pins are connected with the slider in one position, "B" in the other. I'd verify with a continuity tester just to be sure; datasheets aren't guaranteed to be 100% accurate.

Comment: yea, i will test it once i got the component. Thanks

Comment: I would hazard a guess, also, that "A" is the position in which the switch is supplied, because it's shown with a solid line while B has a dashed line. Don't rely on that unless the datasheet specifically says so though!

Answer (score 0):

The last page of this [datasheet of the same P/N](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_SHOU-HAN-MSK12C02_C431540.pdf) shows the similar switching diagram but also includes the SMT pattern with the pins 1,2,3, (and frame as pin 4) clearly marked.

Answer (score 0):

It's an SPDT / 1P2T slide switch.

[image]

The common terminal is 'C'.

The connection is between 'C' & '1' in position 1 and between 'C' & '2' in position 2.